# How to bulk delete lambda functions using AWS Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, command-line-interface

I have around 200 lambda functions that I need to delete. Using the console I can only delete one at a time, which would be really painful. Does anyone know a cli command to bulk delete all the functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just found an answer using an old script to delete IAM users I had:

```
aws lambda list-functions --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.Functions | .[] | .FunctionName' |
while read uname1; do
echo "Deleting $uname1";
aws lambda delete-function --region us-east-1 --function-name $uname1;
done
```

Comment: Note: Had to `brew install jq` to run this on MacOS

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner without having to use `jq`:

```
$ aws lambda list-functions --region us-east-1 --query 'Functions[].FunctionName' --output text | tr "\t" "\n" | xargs -I {} aws lambda delete-function --region us-east-1 --function-name {}
```

Comment: I definitely prefer this one-liner and like using the built-in `--query` option too.